# How to start css and html

Tags: html, css

I have general question how to start developing my skills in web designing.
What is best place to start and what technique to use.
I have some knowledge of html and css, so far I have been building sites with already done all html and css. I would just use it and maybe do a smaller changes.
I want to be able to make html and css out of image that artistic guy produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the really "artsy" sites are produced in another program first, usually Adobe Photoshop or Adobe Illustrator, and then 'sliced' into HTML div's.  [NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/) has a handful of tutorial on how these that show the complete start-to-finish.  Here's a few I found real quick:

- [Design and Code a Slick Website from Scratch – Part I](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-tutorials/design-and-code-a-slick-website-from-scratch-%E2%80%93-part-i/)
- [How to Design and Code a Flexible Website](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-design-and-code-a-flexible-website/)
- [New Plus Tutorial: Convert a Beautiful PSD to HTML and CSS](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/new-plus-tutorial-convert-a-beautiful-psd-to-html-and-css/)
- [Coding a Beautiful Website From Scratch: Plus Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/coding-a-beautiful-website-from-scratch-plus-tutorial/)

(the last 2 I think you have to be a paying member for)

Answer (score 8):

http://w3schools.com/ has some great tutorials and you can play around with stuff right their on their pages.

Comment: That's what I started with. Then moved on to some books. But nothing beats just trying one out for yourself. Hands on experience is the best, IMO.

Comment: Which is what is nice about w3schools, you can do some hands on stuff right in the tutorials.  Makes the transition easier.  Of course there is never any substitute for solving real-world problems.

Comment: w3schools is nice because they have tutorials, examples, AND reference materials.  One stop shopping.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great web resource to check out for HTML/CSS: http://htmldog.com/

Also, do a Google search for "psd slicing."  This is the process of taking an image of a website layout (a.k.a. mockup) and turning into valid HTML/CSS.  You'll find a lot of screen casts and tutorials that will walk you through the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting a book and look at some tutorials. Google will help you there. Once you've got a decent idea of what's going on, look at a site, and try to duplicate what it looks like. If you're curious as to how something works or can't figure it out, look at the source (preferably with firebug) :D

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, getting a good book on HTML/CSS will certainly help.

Also read up on Web Standards - I think its really important to start learning these principles from the beginning as it will help you write valid HTML/CSS... and avoid writing invalid code.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest the book "CSS Mastery". It's got a green cover with a pink binding...I think they've recently released a new version actually. Amazing book for beginning and advanced. I consider it my CSS bible.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and the [Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/).  I like most of the book in the head first series, in fact.  They take a fun very visual approach to learning & I am a visual learner.  Lots of things to practice & hints to help remember things.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel totally confident then definitely pick up Head First HTML. Aside from that there are a few websites I would recommend:
[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/),
[Stop Design](http://stopdesign.com/)
and as others mentioned the W3 website.

Working with a designer often means that they will produce mockups using Photoshop and you will in tern work off those. As that is the case having a working knowledge of Photoshop will be very useful for you. You don't have to be a wizard but some basic knowledge will enable you to do things like create image sprites from the mockup and get information relating to the width, height, color, etc of the different components in the design. As far as getting up to speed quickly there are many books on the subject, the [Photoshop One on One](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521905/) books are a pretty good series and there are video tutorials available at [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/home/ViewCourses.aspx?lpk0=192).

Answer (score 0):

I started on just looking at youtube. A really simple book for learning to code css and html is get coding. It's for kids, but it's a great start. I started there about a year ago, and now I've developed multiple websites for a couple of businesses. And I'm only twelve!